# How to make Apache accept requests, without waiting for client to recv responses?

Tags: apache, sockets, http, protocols, winsock

I wrote a simple socket send routine that sends multiple HTTP requests to apache, essentially logging some data into database (WinSock TCP/IP->Apache->PHP->MySQL). I send HTTP POST request, wait for 200 OK response, then send another HTTP POST request, wait for 200 OK response, ... many times over the same socket. The request-response roundtrip takes ~100 ms. I can't send the next request until I read the response to the previous request, Apache just won't process the requests like that. Otherwise it works fine (if slow).

I'd like to be able to send a continuous stream of requests to Apache, regardless of the responses. I'm ok if the socket closes and some requests will be dropped mid-stream, but if all requests generate "200 OK", I'd like to just send a bunch of packets to Apache, and let Apache process them one by one, responding to each in order. Or even not responding, I don't really care in this particular case.

Is there any way to configure Apache to do that? I don't know enough about sockets to understand why it's necessary to wait to receive HTTP response before sending the next request. I don't know of any fundamental problem with just queuing requests on Apache side, and responding to them in order without waiting for ACK from the client. It probably breaks some protocol rules to queue multiple HTTP requests if they're sent as one packet, but I'm hoping Apache has some way to process this situation. Any help or explanation as to why this is impossible would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply open X connections to the server, and use the first connection which isn't waiting for a response.

Comment: Also note that you should be able to use HTTP pipelining to send multiple requests on the same connection - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining

Comment: Pipelining sounds like exactly what I'm doing (thanks for the link - I didn't know of this feature at all), except my WAMP Apache 2.4 is dropping my 2nd request unless I wait for the response and closes/resets the socket... 
"Non-idempotent methods like POST should not be pipelined. Sequences of GET and HEAD requests can always be pipelined" I'll experiment with it - maybe I need to use GET.
Otherwise, each connection costs resources and takes ~1ms at best, and that's significant for my use case; I'll rather drop requests or spend some dev time coalescing multiple requests into one.

Comment: HTTP pipelining is what you are looking for, however see this: [Does Apache webserver process http pipelined requests in parallel?](http://serverfault.com/questions/266184/does-apache-webserver-process-http-pipelined-requests-in-parallel) and this: [HTTP Pipelining: A security risk without real performance benefits](https://devcentral.f5.com/blogs/us/http-pipelining-a-security-risk-without-real-performance-benefits).

Comment: Thanks for the links! Yes, pipelining is what I was looking for. However, I can't seem to make it work; Apache just won't process anything beyond the first request unless I'm waiting to receive response between requests. Even when I change POST to PUT.